# Fable III: Is it possible to balance the real estate system to maximize rent and keep morality neutral?

Tags: fable-3, fable-2, fable-series

In Fable III, you can set the rent at Low (increases morality), Normal (morality unaffected), and High (decreases morality). That is obvious on a per property basis, but what I'm wondering if it's possible to balance out High and Low rents across multiply properties and keep morality unaffected?

Cases I'm wondering about (are they the same, one better than the other, or does it not work this way at all):

1. If you own 20 properties, have 10 set at High, and 10 set at Low.
2. As close to a 1-to-1 ratio as possible: Cheaper house - Low rent, Expensive house - High rent (taxing the rich, giving to the poor)
3. Setting one wealthy town to all High rent, and one poor town to all Low rent (or is it better balanced in ALL towns individually?).

Ultimately, I suspect that doing any of these pretty much equals the same income as setting everything to neutral, but I also think that may not be the case if you're setting the expensive properties to High rent and cheap ones to Low rent (which...honestly that's how it works here in North America). I would think there might be a significant increase doing method 2.

Also, does this property system work similarly in Fable II?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll do you one better.

**Rent levels do not effect your morality over time.**

Instead you get dinged initially (when you set it), but when you change it back you can get that morality back.  When I tested it, I initially set my properties to high (as I needed money at the beginning) but once I owned all of Albion I pushed it back to low; and my morality came back.

Now I can't be sure it was in equal amounts but it was more than enough to get me over 100% long before the end.

Comment: This is good to know, but I am still curious about balancing High and Low. It'd be cool if you could set it in such a way as to maximize things in general. Personally, money isn't a major issue, it's more just my curious nature and interest in game mechanics.

Comment: @Justin I agree, and I realize I didn't really answer that question for you.  If someone produces a better answer feel free to mark that as correct.

Comment: I bet it would be pretty easy to figure out since, as you pointed out, the results are instant and not over time. Though, it would definitely help out if the display had a numeric value as well. Ultimately, it's really not that big a deal considering how easy it is to get money. I was just curious when I was just starting to build up my real estate and was broke.

Answer (score 2):

Best bet is to uniformly highball or lowball rent globally.

The game remembers very sharply if you discriminated against the Millfields gentry just one rent cycle just because they were rich - this is related to "Primality".

A chaotic mix of lowballing and highballing is possible, but only creates dissonance in your character's "metamorphosis."

The salvific Kingdom Treasury ledger allows for next to everything to be "morally recalibrated" in the latter portion of the game, in any case... Multiple serial murder - nah, nothing... A few million dollars or gold supposedly cleans one's soul...